# Removing random image HTML inside SQL file with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I'm trying to remove a bunch of HTML inside an SQL file with Notepad++. This is probably really easy, but having a hard time trying to understand how to do it.

I want to replace these lines with nothing:

```
<p><img src=\"https://www.example.com/images/folder/screenshots/random_names-384324.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"100%\" height=\"984\" /></p>\r\n
```

Each image has a completely different file name and can be .png, .jpg, etc. The width and height can also change. Everything else is static.

How can I delete them all with regular expressions? I've tried to do it, but it won't find the line when the regular expression is checked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well with regular expressions you’re on the right track. Please provide the expression you tried! // My guess is you didn’t escape enough. Because the SQL is already escaped, the regex will look quite ugly.

Comment: If each is on a new line, you could just do Search > Find > Mark, in the Find What put `<p><img src=` , then tick `Bookmark line` and `Mark All`. Close the find dialog, then go to Search > Bookmark > Cut bookmarked lines.

Comment: [regex and HTML are not good friends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/372239). But regex can be used for simple cases. Please give more examples and expected result.